# Objects within an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have multiple objects like the one below, and I was wondering what the correct syntax would be for putting them all within a single array. I'm also wondering how to correctly cycle through all of the arrays.

```
var verbMap = [
    {
        infinitive: "gehen",
        thirdPres: "geht",
        thirdPast: "ging",
        aux: "ist",
        pastPart: "gegangen",
        english: "go"
    },
    {
        infinitive: "gelingen",
        thirdPres: "gelingt",
        thirdPast: "gelang",
        aux: "ist",
        pastPart: "gelungen",
        english: "succeed"
    }
];
```

I know the correct way to cycle through that above array is:

```
for(v in verbMap){
    for(p in verbMap[v]){
    }
}
```

If I wanted to cycle through a larger array holding multiple arrays like `verbMap`, what would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: Note that those inner "arrays" are in fact objects (`{}`), not arrays (`[]`).

Comment: In JavaScript, everything is an object ;-)

Comment: @Zach L.: Yes, but not everything is an array :)

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop for arrays, use `for...in` for objects.

Comment: When first learning javascript I also confused the plain object `{}` to be an associative array (like in php, for example) because you can use the same syntax: `someObject["item"]`. Instead of thinking of this as an associative array, think of it as a hashtable. It makes a lot more sense since arrays are ordered and object properties are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the `verbMap` arrays in another array.

`var verbMaps = [verbMap1, verbMap2...]`

The key thing to understand is that your verbMap is an array of object literals.  Only use

`for (k in verbMap)...`

for object literals.

The correct way to loop thru an array is something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < verbMaps.length; i++) {
    var currentVerbMap = verbMaps[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < currentVerbMap.length; j++) {
        var currentHash = currentVerbMap[j];
        for (var k in currentHash) {
           console.log(k, currentHash[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to write that out a table, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/wANRp/ do you know how I would do that?

Comment: @Andrew start by changing the outer loop to use `var i;...` as outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following function outputs every value from a (possibly) infinite array given as a parameter.

```
function printInfiniteArray(value){
    if (value instanceof Array){
        for(i=0;i<value.length;i++){
            printInfiniteArray(value[i]);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Edited code. Thanks jtfairbank

Comment: Do not use for...in with arrays in javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Your array does not contain other arrays. It contains objects. You could try this to loop though it.

```
for(var i = 0; i < verbMap.length; i++)
{
   var obj = verbMap[i];
   alert("Object #"+ i " - infinitive: " + obj.infinitive);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would treat the array like any other javascript object.

```
var arrayOfArrays = [];
var array1 = ["cows", "horses", "chicken"];
var array2 = ["moo", "neigh", "cock-adoodle-doo"];

arrayOfArrays[0] = array1;
arrayOfArrays[1] = array2;
```

You can also use javascript's literal notation to create a multi-dimentional array:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [ ["meat", "veggies"], ["mmmm!", "yuck!"] ];
```

To cycle through the array of arrays, you'll need to use nested for loops, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
    var myArray = arrayOfArrays[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
        var myData = myArray[0]; // = arrayOfArrays[0][0];
    }
}
```

DO NOT USE For...in!!!
That is not what it was made for.  In javascript, For...in can have some unwanted behaviors.  See [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to cycle through an array or object, without having to check which one it is. A simple recursive function to cycle through key-value pairs in a nested structure, without knowing the exact depth:

```
var walk = function(o) {
    $.each(o, function(key, value) {
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            walk(value);
        } else {
            console.log(key, value);
        }
    });
}
```